# Get Char's directionality in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, char

I have a method in Java, that takes a Hebrew string, and adjusts its end to a form appropriate to Hebrew. In one of the lines I used in a property `Character.getDirectionality(char)`.

Now, I want to "translate" it to JavaScript. The problem is that I can't find appropriate way to get this property. Yes, there is an option to search in the [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt), but this is 1) can have some problems with the copyright; and 2) it is seems hard. Maybe, there is an Unicode library for JS, or a built-in solution.

Here is my code in Java (I did some corrections in it, but it donesn't matter so much):

```
public static String endingPointed(String s) {
        int i=s.length()-1; //max. length of the while loop
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(s);    //mutable String I will change during the method
        while(i>=0) {   //the loop
            //i.e. vocalization checking
            if(Character.getDirectionality(s.charAt(i))==Character.DIRECTIONALITY_NONSPACING_MARK){
                i--;
            if(sofiyot.contains(s.charAt(i)+"")) {  //next letters: כמנפצ; they have ending form
                sb.replace(i, i+1, (char) (s.charAt(i)-1)+"");  //replacement to the ending form
                if(s.endsWith("כ")||s.endsWith("כּ"))
                    sb.append("ְ"); //if a pointed word ends with 'ך', the letter accepts schva ('ְ'). Ex. "אֵיךְ" (ekh), means 'how'
                return sb.toString();
            }
            if(patach.contains(s.charAt(i)+"")) {   //in the pointed writing, the letters החע accept patach ('ַ'). Ex. "תַּפּוּחַ" (tapuakh), means 'apple'
                if(!s.endsWith("ָ"+s.charAt(i))&!s.endsWith("ַ"+s.charAt(i)))   //except when the letters are dotted with patach ('ַ') or kamatz ('ָ')
                    sb.append("ַ");
                return sb.toString();
            }
            else
                return sb.toString();
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There could easily be a CSS solution (though I don't quite understand the problem; I'm not a Hebrew speaker).

Comment: Can you clarify what does `endingPointed` do? What is the *adjusts its end to a form appropriate to Hebrew*?

Comment: From reading the code, it looks like you're trying to do something that, in the way computers are currently designed, the _font_ is meant to do. You shouldn't _need_ to do that in JavaScript; just change to a font that properly supports Hebrew writing.

Comment: It turns, for example the string `יָרִימ`, that is illegal in Hebrew, to `יָרִים`, the legal form.

Comment: The font **cannot** do it. The final forms have separate codes in Unicode.
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_form) is the additional reading about final letters in Hebrew.
In certain cases Hebrew words may end with non-final forms, as in word `טראמפ` (Trump), and this can occur in borrowings.

Comment: Would `/\p{Nonspacing_Mark}/u.test(char)` suffice? See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-unicode-property-escapes

Comment: Wow! Thank you, [vsemozhebuty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2625560/vsemozhebuty)!!!